# splitting random strings in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a string with random numbers,

like **"12345678912234"**

I want to split it into 4 parts, like,

**string1 = 123**

**string2 = 456**

**string3 = 7891**

**string4 = 2234**

anybody has any idea??

I've tried using NSRange but I cannot get it. May be I'm using it wrong.

I also tried using `substringToIndex` but it failed too.

Comment: By which criteria do you want to split the string? equal substrings? random substrings? etc...

Comment: What is the criteria of splitting? Always 3,3,4,4 split? Always length same?

Comment: yes the length will always same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(NSString *)splitString:(NSString *)string fromX:(int)x toY:(int)y
{
    NSRange range = { x, y};
    return [string substringWithRange:range];
}


        NSLog([self splitString:@"12345678912234" fromX:0 toY:3]);
        NSLog([self splitString:@"12345678912234" fromX:3 toY:3]);
        NSLog([self splitString:@"12345678912234" fromX:6 toY:4]);
        NSLog([self splitString:@"12345678912234" fromX:10 toY:4]);
```

Just tested it :) Works fine. (Just to clarify: I have named the function incorrectly as it is not toY but how many characters you want to take in from X).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use substringWithRange.